# Magento 2 multiple shipping options on checkout

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping, methods, multiple

**Is there a way to create something like:**

1. Free Shipping
2. 3 days delivery (+5£)
3. Next day Delivery (+9£)

so the customer can choose on checkout? Is there a module to do this?

Comment: Try [this](https://www.mageworx.com/magento-2-shipping-suite.html) module

Answer (score 3):

I've used the [WebShopApps MatrixRate Shipping module](https://marketplace.magento.com/webshopapps-module-matrixrate.html) on a couple websites and it works great. You can do exactly what you are wanting to do with this module. Create multiple shipping options like:

1. Free Shipping
2. 3 days delivery (+5£)
3. Next day Delivery (+9£)

You can also set different shipping options and different prices based on the shipping location. You just upload a CSV file through your Magento admin.